# Mobile data turns on automatically

Tags: mobile-data, 9.0-pie, motorola

I am using Moto One power mobile and android version is 9.0 pie. I have two sim cards in my device, and one is used for data. The other one's data switches on automatically, and there is no active data pack on that sim; so it deducts from my main account balance. How can I stop that?

Answer (score 0):

**It has been fixed in the Feb patch Update,**

just Go Settings -> About phone -> System updates -> Now update